# How upload reactjs project to ftp?

Tags: reactjs

I'm newbie on react, I did 2 paged website for exercise, all is working well on my localhost.

But i'm confused about how upload project to my linux server.

What i did ? 
I create react app via terminal with this command :

```
create-react-app react-demo-project
```

Terminal create my project and in project root i have **node_modules** directory.

so here is i have some questions:

1- React project will work normally on linux hosting?

2- I need to all my project upload to ftp? Because there is arround 20.000 file in node_modules directory.

Answer (score 31):

With this command build your app :

```
npm run build
```

Build folder has created in your project directory, open index.html in your browser and check output...

If you saw a blank page (after build and opening index.html) , you must change the main js file path in the index.html :

default is : `src="/static/js/main.ddfa624a.js"`
change to : `src="./static/js/main.ddfa624a.js"`

I changed js path and this worked !

Comment: Is there a way to not have to change this every time I run a new build?

Comment: Life saver... But also curious about @KrisJones 's question

Comment: Add this line to package.json:
"homepage": "./" - then you don't need to change the index.html every time

Answer (score 8):

create-react-app has a command to bundle your app to a ready to deploy state.

`npm run build`

This command will bundle your app in `/build` folder. With the contents of this folder you can deploy your app in any hosting environment. You don't need to install your packages and libraries manually when you use this command. More information about using this command and deploying your app in different hosting environments can be found [create-react-app README](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment)

> ### Deployment
>
> `npm run build` creates a `build` directory with a production build of
>   your app. Set up your favorite HTTP server so that a visitor to your
>   site is served `index.html`, and requests to static paths like
>   `/static/js/main.<hash>.js` are served with the contents of the
>   `/static/js/main.<hash>.js` file.

Comment: i did it, npm run build and then uploaded to server what have in build folder, when i open page from browser. I see just white blank page

Comment: here is console giving:main.2963645a.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
main.bb6aff2b.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
main.2963645a.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Probably your hosting environment is not setup right to serve contents from the static directory.

Comment: interesting, when i look to assets-manifest.json i see that js files in right path

Comment: I think it also depends on the type of server. For most apps, you will need a web server that uses HTTP. If you upload to a FTP server, which uses FTP and not HTTP, your page won’t work. However, pre-rendered static HTML files will.

Answer (score 5):

> 1- React project will work normally on linux hosting?

Yes, it will work in all webservers, unless you have server side rendering (SSR)

> 2- I need to all my project upload to ftp? Because there is arround
> 20.000 file in node_modules directory.

Files in node_modules will **NOT** go to your web server. These are development dependency files used only during development.

1. Run npm run build
2. This will create a folder called `build` in project root. This will have all html, css , images and js files
3. Copy all files and folders in `build` folder **to your site root**.

If your site has to be hosted in a sub folder in root you need to do the below, otherwise you will see a blank page. This is because your static files (css, js etc) are not loaded correctly.

Open package.json
Add a new entry `homepage: /your_subfolder/`

It will look like this

[image: homepage in package.json]

Now do steps mentioned above and your site should work fine

Comment: Great! Concise and accurate steps that I needed!

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to `package.json`:

```
"homepage": "./"
```

That should make it work without the need to adjust index.html after every build.

[image]

Comment: question was asked 4 years before

Comment: So what? I still ran into the same problem without an answer...

Comment: sorry i don't have twitter